# white-coloured light brick for the iron man sets

Tags: electronics, set-modification, lighting

I've recently built the Marvel Iron Man Figure (76206) which comes with a [light brick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54930c02) to power the 'arc reactor' in the set

[image]

[image]

I find it problematic that the light brick lights up orange, rather than the white/bright blue like in the movies. The transparent blue plate doesn't do much to modify the colour.
I'm also building the Hulkbuster 76210 set next, which according to online reviews has the same problem with the 3 light bricks included.

Is there a third party source where I could buy alternative or modified light bricks? Does anyone have or can produce instructions to exchange the LED in a Lego light brick?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not aware of 3rd party sellers that offer these in alternate colors, but it doesn't look terribly difficult to do yourself. There is at least one [video covering the process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rhcr5wX0-SE). Here's the gist:

1. Take the base off with a screwdriver

[image: Disassembly step 1]

2. Remove the original LED

[image: Disassemble set]

3. Acquire a suitable replacement LED of the appropriate color and voltage

[image: New LED]

4. Bend and trim the leads on the new LED

[image: Lead trimming]

5. Test and reassemble

[image: Photo showing alternate LED color]

Comment: FYI LEDs don't come in different voltages separately from colours. However I expect the voltage doesn't have to be matched.

Comment: @user253751 It won’t need to be an _exact_ match, but too far off won’t work well. Something between 2.9V and 3.1V should be fine, and you can get most colors in that size in that voltage range. For example, an Inolux INL-3AW30 should work perfectly well here (though that is admittedly the _only_ 3mm through-hole white LED around the right voltage range I found with a cursory search through my usual go-to for this type of thing).

Comment: Great pictures.  Thanks for another awesome answer.

Comment: I can attest that the method described here works well, I've used white leds we had lying around at work my colleague measured out to work quite well with 3V